# How do I return a vector element from a Rust function?

Tags: vector, reference, rust

I would like to return an element of a vector:

```
struct EntryOne {
    pub name: String,
    pub value: Option<String>,
}

struct TestVec {}

impl TestVec {
    pub fn new() -> TestVec {
        TestVec {}
    }

    pub fn findAll(&self) -> Vec<EntryOne> {
        let mut ret = Vec::new();
        ret.push(EntryOne {
            name: "foo".to_string(),
            value: Some("FooVal".to_string()),
        });
        ret.push(EntryOne {
            name: "foo2".to_string(),
            value: Some("FooVal2".to_string()),
        });
        ret.push(EntryOne {
            name: "foo3".to_string(),
            value: None,
        });
        ret.push(EntryOne {
            name: "foo4".to_string(),
            value: Some("FooVal4".to_string()),
        });

        ret
    }

    pub fn findOne(&self) -> Option<EntryOne> {
        let mut list = &self.findAll();

        if list.len() > 0 {
            println!("{} elements found", list.len());
            list.first()
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test = TestVec::new();
    test.findAll();
    test.findOne();
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5eba731d9b15d177b5a6b2a35e4f2a47&version=stable))

I always get this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:40:13
   |
35 |     pub fn findOne(&self) -> Option<EntryOne> {
   |                              ---------------- expected `std::option::Option<EntryOne>` because of return type
...
40 |             list.first()
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `EntryOne`, found &EntryOne
   |
   = note: expected type `std::option::Option<EntryOne>`
              found type `std::option::Option<&EntryOne>`
```

How do I return an element?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a value and a reference to a value?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ok, but how do I return the element by value? Can I clone/copy it?

Comment: @Shepmaster I already tried, but not work
`pub fn findOne(&self) -> Option<EntryOne> {self.findAll().first().cloned()}`
no method named `cloned` found

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at the signature for [`Vec::first`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.first):

```
fn first(&self) -> Option<&T>
```

Given a reference to a vector, it will return a reference to the first item if there is one, and `None` otherwise. That means that the vector containing the values must outlive the return value, otherwise the reference would point to undefined memory.

There are two main avenues:

1. If you cannot change the vector, then you will need to make a copy of your data structure. The easiest way to do this is to annotate the structure with `#[derive(Clone)]`. Then you can call [`Option::cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.cloned) on the result of `first`.
2. If you can change the vector, then you can remove the first value from it and return it. There are many ways of doing this, but the shortest code-wise is to use the [`drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) iterator.

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct EntryOne {
    name: String,
    value: Option<String>,
}

fn find_all() -> Vec<EntryOne> {
    vec![
        EntryOne {
            name: "foo".to_string(),
            value: Some("FooVal".to_string()),
        },
        EntryOne {
            name: "foo2".to_string(),
            value: Some("FooVal2".to_string()),
        },
        EntryOne {
            name: "foo3".to_string(),
            value: None,
        },
        EntryOne {
            name: "foo4".to_string(),
            value: Some("FooVal4".to_string()),
        },
    ]
}

fn find_one_by_clone() -> Option<EntryOne> {
    find_all().first().cloned()
}

fn find_one_by_drain() -> Option<EntryOne> {
    let mut all = find_all();
    let mut i = all.drain(0..1);
    i.next()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", find_one_by_clone());
    println!("{:?}", find_one_by_drain());
}
```

Additional changes:

1. There's no need for `TestVec` if there's no state; just make functions.
2. Rust style is `snake_case` for method and variable names.
3. Use `vec!` to construct a vector when providing all the elements.
4. Derive `Debug` so you can print the value.

---

If you wanted to always get the *last* element, you can use `pop`:

```
fn find_one_by_pop() -> Option<EntryOne> {
    find_all().pop()
}
```